# How can I sent an anchor's href attribute value from state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set an anchor's `href` attribute from my state, once I know what the URL is.

I am attempting:

`<a href={this.state.uri} target="_blank">`

I log the state.uri, and the uri is correct.

`https://www.exaple.com/myfile.pdf`

However, when the code runs and the href value gets set, and I click it, it tries to navigate to:

`http://localhost:8080/%22https://www.example.com/myfile.pdf%22`

How do I successfully update the href value oif a button from a state value?

State is set:

```
this.setState({
      isDownloading: this.props.isDownloading,
      uri: this.props.uri
    });
```

And the actual code for the button:

```
<a href={this.state.uri} target="_blank">
          <button className="w3-btn w3-round w3-blue" disabled={this.state.isDownloading}>Download</button>
        </a>
```

Someone may have hit it... when I log state, I see this:

[image]

I am checking why this is...

Comment: Can you show some code, preferably `setState`?

Comment: Added the code. Note that if I log the value... the state.uri is correct.

Comment: when is the call `this.setState`?

Comment: Show the props from where this URI is being passed along. It seems like your uri has surounding `"` (speech marks) (see the `%22`)

Comment: I think you found it. I see the quotes. I am working out why this is, as I get the result from an api call result.

Comment: Maybe you need to `JSON.parse()` the value there :)

Comment: @Craig Seeing that this is a data error and not a code problem, will the question be deleted / closed from your side?